# Did the phrase "ball and chain" referring to one's wife originate in U.S. black culture?

Tags: slang, phrase-origin

[*Green's Dictionary of Slang*](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/gvvixqi#7g4zuxa) has this to say about the phrase **"ball and chain."**

> *(orig. US black)* one’s wife or regular girlfriend; thus *ball-and-chained*, married.

However, the earliest citations provided in *GDoS* are from white fiction writers.

> - **1924**    [US]    Hecht & Bodenheim *Cutie* 62: So this is the way you have been deceiving me! [...] with a **ball and chain** waiting for
>     you at home.
> - **1928**    [US]    Hecht & MacArthur *Front Page* Act I: sheriff: Oh, hello, dear. kruger: Sounds like the **ball and chain**.
> - **1929**    [US]    H.C. Witwer *Yes Man’s Land* 185: ‘Oh, please don’t start a row, Egbert!’ murmurs his **ball-and-chain**.

[Maxwell Bodenheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_Bodenheim) was a white writer from Mississippi. [Ben Hecht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Hecht) was a white Chicago writer, though notably also a journalist with no fear of the underground.  As Wikipedia describes,

> At the age of 16, Hecht ran away to Chicago, where, in his own words, he "haunted streets, whorehouses, police stations, courtrooms, theater stages, jails, saloons, slums, madhouses, fires, murders, riots, banquet halls, and bookshops."

[H.C. Witwer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._C._Witwer) is likewise a white American fiction writer.

I was not able to find any assertions for or against the claim that the phrase was originally from U.S. black culture in other sources, including [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ball+and+chain), [phrases.org](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/54950.html), and the [*Online Slang Dictionary*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/old-ball-and-chain,-the).

**Questions**:

1. What evidence is there suggesting that the phrase originated in U.S. black culture?
2. Are there any earlier citations than the ones from *GDoS*?
3. What are the earliest known uses by a black writer?

Comment: I've never read anything to suggest that this idiom originated in black or slave culture.  I'd say it was more prison-oriented than slave-oriented.

Comment: OED gives an earlier citation: [1921](https://books.google.com/books?id=r6XfV16kcosC&pg=RA26-PA24&lpg=RA26-PA24&dq="How%27s+the+ball+and+chain?").

Comment: Given that *ball and chain* was a typical method of restraining slaves, it seems quite likely that this might have evolved as slang among their culture. Circumstantial evidence, of course, but it also seems likely it would have evolved primarily as spoken language, and it sadly isn’t surprising that the more literate and educated white authors would put it into print first.

Comment: @WillCrawford - I don't recall ever seeing a portrayal of a slave bearing ball and chain.  Most often, if chains were present, the depiction was of multiple slaves chained together.

Comment: [Slave Shackles, c. 1850](https://digital.library.illinois.edu/items/c7ac8280-0d92-0135-23f6-0050569601ca-7) — picture doesn’t include a ball, but the text below includes *and the ball and chain were also used*.

Comment: You'll find a lot more depictions of prisoners (typically in striped clothing) with ball and chain.

Comment: [print reference](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_oerDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT64&ots=D4byDLTxHE&dq=were%20balls%20and%20chains%20actually%20worn%20by%20slaves%3F&pg=PT64#v=onepage&q=were%20balls%20and%20chains%20actually%20worn%20by%20slaves?&f=false)

Comment: The prisoners are usually in a *chain gang* aren't they?

Comment: @HotLicks  - “Gone with the wind” comes to mind when Scarlet O’Hara hires convicted black people on blocks and chains to work for her carpentry because they were payed   less than other black people. what year was that?

Comment: @user5768790 - But they were prisoners, not slaves.

Answer (score 2):

There is an earlier reference in OED :

> 1921   Collier's 25 June 24/3   He deliberately attempts to commit suicide by askin' me ‘How's the ball and chain?’ meanin' my wife.

But the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/261231?redirectedFrom=ball+and+chain#eid122087472) also cites an even earlier cross-reference under the 'ball and chain' collocation used in reference to a wife, which cross-reference indicates a meaning within matrimony generally, which may have given rise to the more specific reference to wives :

> 1855   Defiance (Ohio) Democrat 10 Feb. 1/5   Wives..are less eager to enjoy their independence than to assert it. They do not cast off altogether the ball and chain of their matrimonial bonds, but show themselves so restless, that they keep their legal guardians in a state of constant suspicion and anxiety.

Answer (score 1):

In volume five of "In Search of Lost Time," *The Captive & The Fugitive*, Marcel Proust describes having to go back to his mistress, Albertine, "as to a sort of ball and chain to which I was somehow attached." This was first published in 1923 and and would have been written somewhat earlier.

Comment: Are you saying the phrasing was originally French and borrowed through a translation? Or do you think the translator chose 'ball and chain' as the closest corresponding metaphor for some other French wording?

Comment: Per the next post, it seems to have been an appropriated metaphor. I was merely pointing out an early usage that I happened to encounter. I'm not sure whether it is an artefact of translation or not.

Answer (score 1):

The ball and chain goes back to seventeenth and eighteenth century England, when this type of device was used to restrain prisoners from running away (perhaps when engaged in hard labour).  It is not difficult to see how this gets extended to be a not very flattering reference by an allegedly henpecked husbands to their wives as restrictions on their freedom of conduct in all sorts of ale ways.  I do not think it as all likely that any male slave would be tempted to refer to his wife (if he were even allowed to have one) in this way.  It sounds more in keeping with the cockney rhyming slang expression for 'wife' and 'trouble and strife' (or 'trouble' for short).  I got the dating from *vocabulary.com*.

Comment: I think we can all agree that it is a plausible metaphor that a chauvinistic man might think appropriate. But is there any evidence in writing from the seventeenth and eighteenth centuries that uses the metaphor in this way?

Comment: @Mitch:  Not as far as I am aware.  It is, as I understand it, the non-metaphorical balls and chains that are referred to in the 17th and 18th century.